# How to update phpmyadmin on hosted website?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a personal home page and I decided to start a server. I use ipage.com and their phpmyadmin is an old version. How to update to the newest 3rd version? I've read documentations and the problem is that : I don't see where is the phpmyadmin folder in my websites files. It looks embedded inside ipages. Am I stuck with an old version of phpmyadmin forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's a shared hosting, not a VPS/VDS? I mean you are not allowed to login with ssh and install software...

In this case you could only contact tech support with the proposal to upgrade phpmyadmin. If they are not willing to help you with that - change hosting or setup your own VPS/VDS, which is more expensive, but you get full control of your OS.

The most heavy limitation you will probably have in this case: Hosting company provides you a special kernel, and you are unable to configure it...

Comment: Can I host my own mysql and phpadmin on my PC by connecting to the server?

Comment: Do you mean "Can you install and use your own mysql and phpmyadmin on your own server?"

Comment: What do you mean by "your own server"? I though my server is the one from the webpage I bought

Comment: Your shared hosting provides disk space for your website's files and ability to create databases on their mysql server. But they decide what version of Apache/MySQL/PHP/PHPMyAdmin their clients will use. Please [read this information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service#Types_of_hosting) carefully

Answer (score 1):

Probably yes - for shared hosting sites you generally have one set of tools (i.e. phpmyadmin) installed that all users of that server share.

You can ask the hosting company to update their server, but if they don't, you're largely out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they host the phpMyAdmin for you. Some companies will let you install your own version and you can use that.